# How do I make the picture tile in Share Point Picture Libraries transparent?

Tags: css, image, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Greetings Stack Overflow,

I humbly request assistance with a Sharepoint 2013 issue. I have a picture library in SP and it defaults to having a colored tile box over the image that expands when I hover over it. This is obscuring the finer details of some images. As such, my goal is to remove this box *or make it transparent*. Using related SO questions and fiddling around with inspect source, I have been trying to insert code into the Thumbnail.aspx in Sharepoint designer and have been wholly unsuccessful. An example of one such attempt is:

< style>
.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox
{color:#fff;background-color: rgb(4 55 66 / 0%);position:absolute;top:130px;}
< /style>

[image: before/after]

Here is [a before and after example of what I am hoping to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgx4l.png). I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue, or even any pointers towards an authoritative source on the subject.

Regards,

S

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `opacity: value` to set element transparency.But when the transparency is to zero,the picture name will not be seen.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Test result:

[image]

The picture on the left shows the style has been modified

Answer (score 0):

To make the color of the box transparent, you can apply.

```
background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0);
```

where the 4th value indicates transparency. Takes value between 1 and 0.